# how can I store multiple id's for an instance of the join table in my seed file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, database-migration, has-many-through, seeding

The code below is my seeds file. I've already set up the has many through relationship in the migration and models. I'm wondering how I can create an instance of recipeingredient with multiple ingredients. What I have below returns null for recipeingredient.

```
Ingredient.delete_all
Recipe.delete_all
RecipeIngredient.delete_all

butter = Ingredient.create(name: 'Butter', image: 'butter.png')
cinnammon = Ingredient.create(name: 'Cinnammon', image: 'cinnammon.png')
Ingredient.create(name: 'Cocoa Powder', image: 'cocoa.png')
Ingredient.create(name: 'Cream Cheese', image: 'cream-cheese.png')
Ingredient.create(name: 'Eggs', image: 'eggs.png')
Ingredient.create(name: 'Flour', image: 'flour.png')
Ingredient.create(name: 'Heavy Cream', image: 'cream.png')
Ingredient.create(name: 'Milk', image: 'milk.png')
Ingredient.create(name: 'Nuts', image: 'nuts.png')
Ingredient.create(name: 'Oil', image: 'oil.png')
Ingredient.create(name: 'Salt', image: 'salt.png')
Ingredient.create(name: 'Sugar', image: 'sugar.png')
Ingredient.create(name: 'Vanilla', image: 'vanilla.png')

ccp = Recipe.create(name: 'Chocolate Chip Cookies', difficulty: 1)
cheesecake = Recipe.create(name: 'Cheesecake', difficulty: 2)

RecipeIngredient.create(ingredient_id: [cinnammon.id,butter.id],recipe_id: ccp.id)
```

The migrations are :

```
class CreateRecipes < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :recipes do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :difficulty

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateIngredients < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :ingredients do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :image

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateRecipeIngredients < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :recipe_ingredients do |t|
      t.integer :recipe_id
      t.integer :ingredient_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I've tried creating the recipeingredient instance with the actual integer of recipe_id or ingredient_id,as well, but it didn't work either. Could I maybe use serialize? Not sure how serialize works though. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

be sure to have the relations well configured

```
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :ingredients, through: :recipe_ingredients
end

class Ingredient < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :recipes, through: :recipe_ingredients
end

class RecipeIngredient < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :ingredient
end
```

then, in your seed file you should have something like this:

```
butter = Ingredient.create(name: 'Butter', image: 'butter.png')
cinnammon = Ingredient.create(name: 'Cinnammon', image: 'cinnammon.png')
a_recipe = Recipe.new(name: 'Recipe name', difficulty: 1)
a_recipe.ingredients << [butter, cinnamon]
a_recipe.save
```

it is not the most elegant solution, but will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

`RecipeIngredient` only accepts a single `ingredient_id`, so for both butter and cinnamon, you have to create one `RecipeIngredient` each:

```
RecipeIngredient.create(ingredient_id: cinnamon.id, recipe_id: ccp.id)
RecipeIngredient.create(ingredient_id: butter.id, recipe_id: ccp.id)
```

After this, be sure to have the has many relationship setup in your `recipe.rb`

```
has_many :ingredients
```

You can then call `ccp.ingredients` to display cinnamon and butter.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work and return an argument error